# Problems with polymorphic array Java

Tags: java, arrays

These unit tests only print out messages of testing problems. If your code is correct, the unit tests will succeed silently without any success messages. I need to get this to light up without any error messages. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and I am a fairly new programmer so bear with me here. It's the GetCourseByCourseID method that I am having an issue finishing.I am not supposed to make changes to any class besides CourseList. Specifically the GetCourseByCourseID method.

```
class CourseList  
{
public Course[] CourseArray =
{
    new Course ("CIS 400", "OO Analysis & Design", 4, "Important class", "CIS 110") ,
    new Course ("CIS 150A" , "VB.NET Programming", 4, "Good Introduction to programming", "CIS 100") ,
    new Course ("CIS 150B", "C# Programming with labs", 4, "Follow-up to CIS 100", "CIS 100")
};


   public Course GetCourseByCourseID(String id)
   {

     for (Course C : CourseArray)
     {

     }
     return null;
   }
}




class CourseListTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseExists();
    GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseDoesNotExist();
  }


public static void GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseExists()
{

    CourseList myCourseList = new CourseList();
    Course myCourse = myCourseList.GetCourseByCourseID("CIS 400");
    if (myCourse.CourseID != "CIS 400")
        System.out.println("ERROR - GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseExists(): Returned CourseID Not equal (CIS 400)");
}

public static void GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseDoesNotExist()
{

    CourseList myCourseList = new CourseList();
    Course myCourse = myCourseList.GetCourseByCourseID("CIS 101");
    if (myCourse != null)
        System.out.println("ERROR - GetCourseByCourseIDTestWhenCourseDoesNotExist(): should have returned null");
}
}



class Course
{
public Course(String id, String title, int creditHours, String description, String prerequisiteCourse)
{
    this.CourseID = id;
    this.CourseTitle = title;
    this.CreditHours = creditHours;
    this.Description = description;
    this.PrerequisiteCourse = prerequisiteCourse;
}


public String CourseID;
public String CourseTitle;
public int CreditHours;
public String Description;
public String PrerequisiteCourse;
```

Comment: This is not [Puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/); don't keep us guessing. Give a thorough explanation of your problem and what you are trying to accomplish, with the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ugly, unreadable code that doesn't follow Java coding standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of the exercise is to verify the `GetCourseByCourseID(String id)` method returns the `Course` corresponding to the specified course ID or `null` if no such course exits.  To achieve this, you have to loop though all the known courses and compare the ID of each course to the `id` parameter.  If a match is found, the course is returned to the caller, otherwise the method returns `null`:

```
public Course GetCourseByCourseID(String id) {

    for (Course C : CourseArray) {
        if (C.CourseID.equals(id)) {
            return course;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I agree with the other posters. Whoever wrote the original code isn't doing you any favors in the long run.  It's very poorly written and definitely non-standard.  If you write code like this, you'll have a lot of bad habits to unlearn later.